# While Deleting the object from AWS S3 bucket, Do we need to give the full URL or we just need to give only name of file in S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, amazon-s3, delete-file

I am using Node js for this problem. I have the bucket name and credentials of the bucket. But I don't know the what we have to add in parameters while deleting the file from the bucket.

I have this kind of URL structure:

```
https://<Region>.amazonaws.com./<Bucket Name>/<File Name>
```

And my parameter object is like:

```
const params = { 

  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,

  Key: fileName !! Doubt what to enter. Full Url or File name        
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide just these 2 params, Bucket and Key. You don't have to provide the complete url. Checkout the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property).